# Установка обоев из python

Tags: python, windows

Здравствуйте, никто не знает, как можно установить обои на рабочий стол средствами питона? ОС - Win7, если это важно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
User=str(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'))
os.system(r'''reg add "hkcu\Control panel\desktop" /v wallpaper /d "'''+ User+r'\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper1.bmp" /f')
os.system(r'''reg add "hkcu\Control panel\desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /d 2 /f''')
os.system(r'''RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True''')
```

Comment: В общем, работает, но почему-то не всегда. 
У меня есть простенький скрипт, который выбирает случайный *.jpg файл и устанавливает приведённым вами способом его на обои. Раза три-четыре подряд срабатывает, потом перестаёт.  По какому принципу - пока не понял. Точно могу сказать только то, что это не рандом случайно несколько раз выбирает один и тот же файл, такую возможность я проверял.
Из-за чего это может быть, не знаете?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример скрипта, меняющего фон рабочего стола:

```py
def set_wallpaper(path):
    import ctypes
    cs = ctypes.c_buffer(path.encode())
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14
    return ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, cs, 0)

set_wallpaper(r'C:\wall.jpg')
```

[Использовал алгоритм тут](https://github.com/gil9red/wallpaper_from_himawari) – скрипт, качающий снимки со спутника и каждые полчаса устанавливащий как фон рабочего стола

Comment: Пока разбирался с тогда этой темой, были какие-то действия с реестром, но вроде бы для этого скрипта этого не нужно делать

Comment: 1- Попробуйте SystemParametersInfoW, чтобы не-ASCII пути поддерживать 2- посмотрите нужно ли в вашем случае последний параметр задать (вместо нуля): `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE |SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE` (1|2)

Comment: `*W()` следует с `path` (Unicode) напрямую использовать. Вообще не понятно, почему не сломалось с `cs` (байты).

Comment: верну ка я пока обратно :D тестировать нет времени и желания )

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import ctypes

folder = r"C:\folder"
file_name = r"back.jpg"

full_path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
wallpaper = bytes(full_path, 'utf-8')

ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, wallpaper, 3)
```

Comment: По сути то же самое, что в ответе gil9red

Comment: И да, и нет, там бывают какие-то сложности с этой задачей, у кого-то один код работает, у кого-то чуть-чуть другой. Мб от версий зависит. Поэтому привела тот код, который у меня работал